# How to configure a javascript file in karate project from external jar file

Tags: karate

I am immersed in the karate features. I have a query related to calling the javascript function from a jar file. I know its a bit madness calling javascript from a jar. I understand your recommendation to use complex custom things where you suggested to use java but we have this requirement. Please help me with this.

I used  **java interop** to call a java function(which is from external jar file where I have created)
In a similar way, I want to access/use a javascript file and use the functions from it. where the javascript file is in the same jar file which I have created.

I am able to access the javascript file from the same project where the javascript file exists in the classpath and declared the file in the karate-config.js file and used the javascript functions inside my feature files

but I am not sure how to access the javascript file or feature file or any file except java file from an external jar

Let me know if you need any further details on my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb - when using from a JAR, use the [`classpath:`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#classpath) prefix.

For example, in JS:

```
var foo = read('classpath:foo.js');
```

Or in a `Feature:`

```
* def foo = read('classpath:foo.js')
```